# Are there any stats for local Google v. Google.com usage?

Tags: google, country-specific, usage-data

Are there any stats for web usage which have attempted to measure how many users in a given country use Google.**com** and how many use the local Google (e.g. Google.**co.uk**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the Experian Hitwise Stats:

US:
http://www.hitwise.com/us/resources/data-center

UK:
http://www.hitwise.com/uk/resources/data-center

The "Top Websites and Search" report should be of interest.

Comment: thanks. they say 85% google.co.uk, 5% google.com, 10% the rest. i'll go with that.